# Pear in SilverStripe?

Tags: php, pear, silverstripe

Does anyone knows how to integrate Pear (http://pear.php.net) and install packages in SilverStripe? My hosting provider doesn't want to install it for me.

Thanks,

Mauro

Comment: What doesn't your hosting provider want to install for you? Pear? Silverstripe?

Comment: My hosting provider doesn't have Pear. The SilverStripe installation works like a breeze, but I need the Pear mail installed to use SMTP authentication instead of the mail() function, which they disabled for security reason.

Comment: You don't need Pear for this feature - use https://github.com/xeraa/silverstripe-smtp instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your hosting provider doesn't have pear and you want to work around that by integrating it in Silverstripe and use it from there but it doesn't really have anything to do with SilverStripe. You just want to be able to use pear. Well, first of all, if your hosting provider doesn't allow pear, it would probably be an illegal move. Second, pear is 'just' a package manager. You can always just copy the files of that Mail package to your server (including all dependences) and put them onto your include path. You don't need the package manager for that.